# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color

Tags: android

```
String abColor = sharedPreferences.getString("action_bar_color", "#ffffff");
String sbColor = sharedPreferences.getString("status_bar_color", "#ffffff");

ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(abColor)));

Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(sbColor));
```

I keep on getting a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color Error referring to the variable `sbColor`. The variable `abColor` works perfectly fine though, even though it is used in the same way as `sbColor`.

Could you please help me to find out why Android Studio is throwing me this error.

```
prefs = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String logged = prefs.getString("LOGGED", "OUT");

mRemoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance();
FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings remoteConfigSettings = new FirebaseRemoteConfigSettings.Builder()
        .setDeveloperModeEnabled(true)
        .build();
mRemoteConfig.setConfigSettings(remoteConfigSettings);

HashMap<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();

defaults.put("action_bar_color", R.color.colorPrimary);
defaults.put("status_bar_color", R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
mRemoteConfig.setDefaults(defaults);

final Task<Void> fetch = mRemoteConfig.fetch(0);
fetch.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        mRemoteConfig.activateFetched();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("action_bar_color", mRemoteConfig.getString("action_bar_color"));
        editor.putString("status_bar_color", mRemoteConfig.getString("status_bar_color"));
        editor.apply();
```

Comment: print the value of sbColor, it may not be what you expect

Comment: What is saved in preferences for `status_bar_color` key?

Comment: you are putting integers and expecting to read strings from the prefs

Comment: @TimCastelijns But `abColor` works fine.

Comment: What is the value of `R.color.colorPrimaryDark`?

Comment: @Les `abColor` prints out a value of #123456, as expected, but sbColor prints out a value of 2131361813.

Comment: @ShobhitPuri It's the default color

Comment: @Zid - then your sbColor is wrong - which is what "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown color" means.  Figure out what the value should be, then figure out why you are getting the wrong value from SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like here: `defaults.put("status_bar_color", R.color.colorPrimaryDark);` you save color as an int resource identifier, but here: `String sbColor = sharedPreferences.getString("status_bar_color", "#ffffff");` you want to load a String representation of color.

So try using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);` in the `defaults.put()` method.

For the `context` argument you can pass `this` (if the method is called within an Activity), or `getActivity()` (if in a fragment).

Now you have to save the color in a String rather than in an int. So do the following:

```
int sbColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
// Convert to String Color
String hexSbColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & sbColor));
defaults.put("status_bar_color", hexSbColor);
```

And you should probably make `defaults` a String-String map:

```
HashMap<String, String> defaults = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: @DmitryAkshin When I put `context` in to the `deafults.put` method, I get an error saying that it cant resolve a symbol.

Comment: @Zid Edited the answer with some clarification.

Comment: Passing `this` doesn't work. And yes, it is in an activity.

Comment: What does it say when you pass it?

Comment: It says that it cannot be applied in a HashMap.

Comment: You using this, right? `ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);`

Comment: Correct, that is what I'm using

Comment: Like this: `defaults.put(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));`

Comment: Use this: `defaults.put("status_bar_color", ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));`

Comment: It wouldn't work though. Now you're saving color as int but loading as String. I'll update the answer in a minute.